# @Schedule vs. @Startup: what will be invoked first

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, startup, schedule

**Class Scheduler:**

```
@Singleton
class Scheduler {
    @Schedule(persistent = false)
    private void task() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Class AppStartup:**

```
@Startup
@Singleton
class AppStartup {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        ...
    }
}
```

What method will be invoked first: Scheduler#task or AppStartup#init if deploy time equals to @Schedule time (00:00:00)

It would be nice to get full components deployment lifecycle by application server (not only @Startup and @Schedule) .

Comment: Have you tried reading the EJB specification?

Comment: Can you name the chapter number? @SteveC

Comment: Chapters 2 thru 13 should cover you...